# why does import pandas suddenly not work?

Tags: python, pandas, conda

I am running the latest `anaconda` on `ubuntu linux`.  Everything was working ok until this week.  I can't `import pandas` on `python3`.  I could last week using the same programs.  I've tried it on `python`  called from the bash and also from `spyder`  and `jupyter`, and I get a message that it can't find `pandas`.  I've tried reinstalling pandas using both `pip` and `conda`, and it said that it was correctly installed.

Any suggestions?

Thank you.

Howard

Comment: are you using the correct conda environment (showing on the most-left of the conda terminal) as for example (base)?

Comment: maybe try first 1. conda deactivate (write on terminal ) 2. conda update --all 3. source activate  name_your_virualenv

Comment: Can you share the contents of the environment?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new environment on Anaconda and then install pandas in that environment. Otherwise, try re-installing Anaconda.